# How to cancel the link like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, connection

I used a NSTimer to get the update data in a link every seconds,and the method like this:

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://disca.malauu.com/jsbfAll.txt"];
NSError *error=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are error"];
NSString *urlData=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"urlString:%@",urlData);
```

And if the network conges,the connection will connect for a long time.How can i cancel it if the link doesn't get the update data with half of second? Who can get me a answer,Think you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If think you could implement it using `NSURLConnection` and delegate pattern which allow you cancel the connection, and set options like a timeout.
The second advantage is that the request is performed asynchronously, and won't block the execution of your app, if the network doesn't answer immediatly.

You will find more information about this way, on [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) page, and in [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i).

Comment: Ye,Thank you for your reply to my question.I konow the NSURLConnection,and i used it much times.But this time,i get the data for every second,and i get it from a txt form. i cantn't use  the　method　of 'stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:' like this?  And how to get the data more fast,do you have any advice?

Comment: I think you can set your timer to launch an asynchronous request if and only if the previous call is terminated, or cancel the connection and run a new request

Comment: Yes,i do it like this:-(void) startClock { 
 self.clockViewUpdateTimer = [NSTimer
       scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
       target:self 
       selector:@selector (updateClockView:) 
       userInfo:nil 
       repeats:YES]; 
 NSRunLoop * main=[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [main addTimer:self.clockViewUpdateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
} 
  But if the network conges,the connection will connect for a long time. I mean how to cancel the connection when it conges? Think you.